# Video file URL not found in VideoView

Tags: android, android-videoview

While trying to play a remote video file I am getting the exception:

```
W/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open https://faro.red/movmap/administrar/application/admin/postsmedia/8Lo6H0mapas.mov: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: https://faro.red/movmap/administrar/application/admin/postsmedia/8Lo6H0mapas.mov
```

But the video file is there in this URL:

This is my code:

```
 post_media = prefs.getString("post_media", "no");

        String url = "https://faro.red/movmap/administrar/application/admin/postsmedia/";

        final VideoView videoView;
        videoView = (VideoView)v.findViewById(R.id.video);




        Uri video=Uri.parse(url+post_media);
        videoView.setVideoURI(video);

        videoView.start();
```

Comment: Can you access that URL from a Web browser on your test device? Does your manifest have a `<uses-permission>` element for the `INTERNET` permission?

Comment: @CommonsWare, yes to both questions. When I open the URL from the web browser , the file is directly downloaded